# Iranian postal code validation

Tags: regex, regular-language

Please, I need to validate Iranian postal code using `regex`.
I write this regex for this case `\b([^02\n\D]){4}[^5](\d){5}` but its not working on rule number 5 and 7.
please help me to fix it.

this is some rules about this regex:

1. It's all numeric
2. 10 digit count
3. don't use 0 in first 5 digit
4. don't use 2 in postal code
5. First 4 digit is not the same
6. The 5th digit cannot be 5
7. all digits aren't the same

Comment: In particular add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and detail the rules with samples of what does match or not.

Comment: This seems not to be a job for RegEx after all

Comment: Don't count on fourth rule! Many postal codes have 2 in different positions!

Comment: @AliHosseinzadeh you're right here with an update without checking 2 in postal code:
                              `^(?!0)\d(?!([0-9])\1{3})[1-9]{3}[1346-9][013-46-9][1-9](?!\1{8})\d$`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following regex satisifes your conditions:

```
\b(?!(\d)\1{3})[13-9]{4}[1346-9][013-9]{5}\b
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QRvRJt/3)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(\d)\1{3})` - negative lookahead to make sure that the 1st 4 digits are not the same.
- `[13-9]{4}` - matches 4 occurrences of all the digits except `0` and `2`
- `[1346-9]` - matches a single digit that is not a `0`,`2` or `5`
- `[013-9]{5}` - matches 5 occurrences of all the digits except `2`
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: I'm really sorry but I read some article about Iranian postal code and that seems `0` can be in the second 5 digit but it can not be in first 5 digits, I fix my question

Comment: @MasOOd.KamYab I have updated the solution. Also, check the demo

Comment: (?!(\d)\1{3}) - negative lookahead to make sure that the 1st 3 digits are not the same.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it came up in the Reopen queue.  This is a very slick answer, but I'd argue that any RegEx that needs 7 bullets to explain will be difficult to maintain, especially if somebody else gets tasked with doing so.

Comment: @WonkotheSane The explanation was needed keeping in mind the different kind of audiences. I try to give an elaborate answer as much as possible, irrespective of its complexity, so that there is less to-and-fro communication in the comments section. :)

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh - I absolutely agree.  I just know that when I come across code that someone has written an elaborate RegEx for, I curse under my breath.  :)